# JS TypeError: texte is null - how to start with a textarea that is not null?

Tags: javascript, null, textarea

I'm new into JS.

I'm trying to get the textarea inputs into the div, and the code I came up with (below) returns the error : `TypeError: texte is null`.

I don't understand why my textarea must be filled and can't be null or undefined, since it should start empty.

JS:

```
const texte = document.getElementById("texte");
const render = document.getElementById("render");

texte.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    render.innerHTML = texte.value;
});
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <textarea rows=5 cols=33 id="texte" name="texte" > test test test test </textarea>

    <button id="ajouter" name="ajouter" >Ajouter</button>

    <div id="render" name="render" >div</div>

</form>
```

Comment: can you add more details about this error? I created a jsFindle with your code and I can't reproduce the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/lido/1ywbkmre/1/

Answer (score 0):

const keyword means the value that can not be changed.
So you need to use var keyword.
And javascript code should be after html elements had been loaded.

```
<form>
    <textarea rows=5 cols=33 id="texte" name="texte" > test test test test </textarea>

    <button id="ajouter" name="ajouter" >Ajouter</button>

    <div id="render" name="render" >div</div>

</form>

<script>
var texte = document.getElementById("texte");
var render = document.getElementById("render");

texte.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    render.innerHTML = texte.value;
});
</script>
```

For line break use the following code.

```
texte.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    render.innerHTML = texte.value.replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + '<br/>' + '$2');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only add event listeners once the document finished loading, or else you risk accessing an element that hasn't been rendered yet.

Try wrapping your entire code with:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

//your code here

}
```